# Handle ajax call using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I want to perform additional operation before calling http request(Ajax GET and POST)

suppose i have following code:

```
function CallHTTP()
{

    $.ajax({
        url: '/abcd/abcd',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function () {
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function (arg1, arg2, arg3) {
            alert("error");
        }

    });

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    CallHTTP();
});
```

i want to handle above request using angularjs interceptor. is it possible ?

I tried following:

```
 angular.module('app', [])
          .config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
              $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$location', '$q', function ($location, $q) {
                  return {
                      'request': function (request) {
                          console.log("abcd");
                          return request;
                      },
                      'responseError': function (response) {
                          if (response.status === 401) {
                              console.log("abcd2");
                              // do stuff
                          }
                          console.log("abcd1");
                          // otherwise, default behaviour
                          return $q.reject(response);
                      }
                  };
              }]);
          }]);
```

but above code doesn't execute when ajax call happens. how to achieve it ?

Thanks.

Comment: An interceptor intercepts a request/response exchange, but it doesn't perform it. You must use `$http`. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: if you want to do it with jquery, use jquery ajax events: 
    $(document).bind("ajaxSend", function () { console.log('before request'); }); https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Answer (score 2):

You are using jquery ajax call and your settings are in the angular interceptor. Use $http to make use of your angular settings.